# Measuring the "flatness" of the likelihood function

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, likelihood, fisher-information

I would like to know if there is a way to measure the flatness of the likelihood for a distribution with a large number of parameters (at least 4 in this case).

I am exploring the Generalized Hyperbolic distribution in the context of maximum likelihood estimation, and something that pops up in literature is the "flatness of the likelihood". This is referring to the gradient of the surface. I want to be able to quantify this notion somehow as this is something that I am not finding in the literature.

Comment: Well, a likelihood that depends on four parameters is a more or less smooth surface in five-dimensional space, and there are notions of [curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature) in such cases. You could look at the maximum curvature, or a suitable global measure (say, integrating over the absolute value of the curvature). What are you trying to do?

Comment: You might also be interested in the [Fisher information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_information) matrix

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "flatness"?

Comment: I am curious how you get to work on exploring the Generalized Hyperbolic distribution before getting across a concept like loglikelihood, score and Fisher Information.

Comment: The term "flatness" might be referring to the Fisher Information.

Comment: Look up [Fisher information](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=fisher-in*+intui*+answers%3A1+duplicate%3Ano)